# Label and sort Thunderbird email

Tags: email, thunderbird

If possible, how can I label (group) received / sent Thunderbird email messages and recall the group in a list for viewing or further processing?  Any references with examples are appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, explained step by step with examples and screenshot

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/message-tags